# Can I implement a transparent, PHP-based authentication layer with Apache's help?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

### Background

I'm looking for a transparent, PHP-driven authentication layer for a web site.

I'm aware of the following simple approaches:

#### HTTP Authentication

Mechanics:

- Apache controls access rights;
- Attempts to access any file in a given directory **transparently** require HTTP auth if not already authed.

Downsides:

- Limited configuration options;
- Difficult to integrate with existing user database;
- No control over visual presentation of login prompt.

#### PHP-based login

Mechanics:

- PHP controls access rights;
- Attempts to access any file **explicitly built for the system** if not already authed will result in redirection to a login page.

Downsides:

- If I forget to write the required `include "login_required.inc.php";` or similar at the top of any PHP file, that file will be accessible by anybody.

---

### What I want

I'd like to implement the **PHP-based login solution**, but to somehow configure Apache to invoke `login_required.inc.php` (or similar) **transparently** as an intermediate step when any PHP file is requested.

This script will:

- run;
- check session variables;
- tell Apache either "yes, produce the requested page" or "no, redirect to the login page";
- not require code to be inserted at the top of every PHP script that requires authentication.

Is this a pipe dream? Or can I do it? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rewrite all php requests through index.php, index.php/php would then control access to anything.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pageid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Something like that will push any request to index.php, in which you can do your authentication and then it will farm out the content...

The QSA in this will retain any query string parameters etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should restructure you website to use a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). There's a reason that pretty much every framework uses the FrontController pattern: single point of access makes your app simpler.

Comment: The most ideal scenario, though if I can avoid restructuring then I'd like to.

Comment: How much work restructuring is really depends on how your app is currently set up. For a very naive and braindead implementation, you could get away with a bunch of rewrite rules and a front controller that munges $_SERVER, $_GET and $_POST to turn them into what the original application expects. Dirty, but it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `.htaccess` `ModRewrite` to redirect all requests to, say, `login_required.php?redirect=<ORIGINALLY-REQUESTED-SCRIPT>`.

`login_required.php` can then perform its magic and do one of the following:

- Present a login form
- `include` `<ORIGINALLY-REQUESTED-SCRIPT>`.
- - Note that a `header("Location: <ORIGINALLY-REQUESTED-SCRIPT>)";` will, I believe, merely fall foul of the `.htaccess` again and cause an infinite redirect loop! Setting the `.htaccess` `ModRewrite` directive to only *conditionally* redirect based on the value of `HTTP_REFERER` is not secure enough.

**This is *not* the preferred solution**, but it's a possibility...

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

Have only a single entry-point. Just one file that's accessible from the outside world, like `index.php?target=<REQUESTED-SCRIPT>`. This one file can contain the authentication logic and `include` the required script.

All other files would be blocked from external access by `.htaccess`, or simple file permissions.

This is a good solution, but **it would be a large change to update *all* URLs throughout the existing system**.

**Edit** Apparently this is called the "Front Controller" pattern.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` does the rewriting for you.

Comment: @Philippe: Actually, that's what I suggested in my other proposal, I think.